# Send Data into BlockChain Network using w3?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, nodejs

HI I want to store my bank information on ethereum network using w3. 
can anyone help me to send my data

//Bank.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;
contract Bank 
{
    struct User 
    {uint userId;
     string email;
     string name;
    }

    mapping(uint => User) public users;
    mapping(uint => string) public userRequestStatus;
    mapping(uint => uint256) public balance;

    function createUserRequest(uint userId_, string memory email_, string memory name_, uint256 amount_ ) public 
    {
        require(users[userId_].userId != userId_,"User Already Exist.");
        User memory user = User( {userId: userId_ , email: email_, name: name_});
        users[userId_]= user;
        balance[userId_] = amount_;
        userRequestStatus[userId_] = "Request send to bank";

    }

    function UpdateAmountRequest(uint userId_, uint256 amount_ ) public 
    {
        require(balance[userId_]== 0,"no data available");
        balance[userId_] = amount_;
        userRequestStatus[userId_] = "after updating balance request in bank";

    }

    function getUserInfo(uint userId_ ) public  view returns(uint userId, string memory email,string memory name) 
    {
        User memory user = users[userId_];
        return (user.userId, user.email, user.name);

    }
    function getUserAmount(uint userId_ ) public  view returns(uint256) 
    {
        return balance[userId_];

    }

}
```

//index.js

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/myAPI"))

var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi, "my Address")
contractInstance.createUserRequest.call(1,"laxman@gamil.com", "laxman", 1000).call((err, result) => { 
    console.log("result", result) ;
    console.log("reerrsult", err) ;
})
```

Comment: Mention the problem you are facing

Comment: I am not able to call method createUserRequest

Comment: can you tell me how I can call this method in Node js and send my data on blockchain network